# Lookup formula in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, formula

I have a financial spreadsheet, in one column is bought items, for instance 'PC Programs'. I want to find the values of only those items in another column and have them placed together in a new column.

Comment: You may want to expand a little, or perhaps provide an example. Please also use tags to help identify what program you're using to view the spreadsheet.

Comment: How about some sample data ? It would help clarify what you wrote (which I still have no idea what you want)

Answer (score 1):

bought items is a boolean?

```
      A           B        C
1 bought Items  price$   NewColumn?
2    1            30     =if(A2 = 1, "true", "false" ) 
3    0            20 
4    0            15
5    1            45
```

formula can also be     =if(A2 = 1, B2 , 0)

I didn't get much what you say but hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Rob. I am happy with what you are saying, however, it must do this in the whole of column A ( or in a range specified), and then table the positive results in column C, in other words, say there was 15 results, put all 15 together so that I can Sum them. (Leave out everything else)

Comment: is still not clear for me, please try to elaborate this a bit more with an example like I did above.

Comment: Bought Items    Price ($)  Results (books)
 pens             12                     20
 books             20                      8
 paper               5                    12
 books               8                   SUM equal 40$
 pens               6 
 paper             10 
 books             12 
 etc.

Comment: what you need is a "group by" and summarize its Items... check this post.

http://superuser.com/questions/405555/how-can-i-group-by-and-sum-a-column-in-excel